# How to show the pin screen

Tags: android, authentication, screen

how can i access the pin screen of my phone to verify that the user is the owner of the phone? I don't want to write my own login screen so if i can get around this and use the one of the phone that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 2.2+, you could use [DevicePolicyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) to lock the screen programatically:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow%28%29

Your activity would than have [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) called when screen is locked, and [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) when it's unlocked. If the user successfully unlocks the screen, he's the owner.

But this wouldn't work if user has no PIN set, so it may not suit your needs here.